# Query array field for multiple values

Tags: postgresql

I have a `roles` field in a `Users` table of type `Array`. I need to be able to get all users that have both role 'admin' and role 'member'. FOr now I use this query:

`select * from users where 'member' = ANY(roles) and 'admin' = ANY(roles);`

I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the array-contained-by operator `@<`:

```
select * from users where ARRAY['member','admin']::varchar[] <@ roles;
```

That'll let you index the lookup too.

(Correction per @bereal; I misread the question)

Or, if you meant that they must have both rights, use array-overlaps `&&`:

```
select * from users where ARRAY['member','admin']::varchar[] && roles;
```

Also, as your input turns out to be `varchar[]` (you didn't show your table definition), you must cast the array input to `varchar[]` too, as there's no implicit cast between array types.

Comment: As far as I understand, that will be equal to `'member' = ANY(roles) OR 'admin' = ANY(roles)`, so rather `<@` aka "is contained by".

Comment: Using that method, I get: ERROR:  operator does not exist: text[] && character varying[]

Comment: @yossarian There's no implicit cast from `text[]` to `varchar[]` so you have to cast explicitly; see edit.

Comment: @yossarian You should rewrite your question to _I need to be able to get all users that have __both__ role 'admin' __and__ role 'member'_